# Firing a Woocommerce hook using a shortcode in post content

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, output-buffering

I am trying to assign the action hook woocommerce_single_product_summary to a shortcode so that, rather than do_action being used in a fixed place in the template, the end-user can move the whole single_product_summary section of the page around freely within a layout they've created in Gutenberg.

I have the following in functions.php:

```
    function getsummary_shortcode( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
    $woocommerce_single_product = ob_get_clean();
    return $woocommerce_single_product;
}

add_shortcode('getsummary','getsummary_shortcode');
```

However, this seems to output the single_product_summary content in an infinite loop.

Is it actually possible to do this? I have found a few posts here trying to do something vaguely similar to this, but none trying to do quite what I'm doing.

Comment: Are there any places within this content that `[getsummary]` exists? does seem interesting its hitting your shotcode again though, I may need to get the woo-commerce code to see how it calls the action hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to deregister, and reregister your `getsummary` shortcode within your function callback to prevent it being called by the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook

```
function getsummary_shortcode( $atts ) {
    remove_shortcode('getsummary');
    ob_start();
    do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
    $woocommerce_single_product = ob_get_clean();
    add_shortcode('getsummary','getsummary_shortcode');
    return $woocommerce_single_product;
}

add_shortcode('getsummary','getsummary_shortcode');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this did the job perfectly! I would never have figured this out - I didn't realise the shortcode had to be added both within the shortcode itself, and outside it?

Comment: Well more so the key is calling `remove_shortcode()` first to prevent anything else calling the same shortcode within `do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' )`, which is what you saw with your recursion loop, then simply adding it again once done means it can be used again if needed.

Realistically I feel like `[getsummary]` is used within your nested content.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the explanation! Yes, ```[getsummary]``` is used in the actual content of the post, added by the user - I'm not sure what else could be calling it, but there is a third-party plugin (FooEvents Bookings) in use on this project that manipulates some of the functions called in ```woocommerce_single_product_summary``` - I suspect that may be responsible, although I've not managed to narrow down in what way yet.